# C# Database Mapper - Object List

Tags: c#, mysql, object

I am using the example provided in another post to map a DB query to a C# object:

[C# Database Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858510/c-sharp-database-mapper)

I cannot see how to utilise it to return a list of objects, can anyone suggest the right answer?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, i advise you to use linq to SQL

Create dbml class see this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/11/19/connect-to-a-sql-database-and-use-the-sql-designer.aspx

Then you can write something like this :

```
var users = new ArrayList();

       using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var query = db.USERS
            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                users.Add(q);
            }
        }

       return users;
```